# How to serve a folder at a specific context using Python's SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, httpserver

I want to serve all the contents of a folder on a different context.

Example: I have a folder called "Original" with index.html in it on my Windows box. If I cd into this folder type in this,

```
 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now I can access the index.html from http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html

How can I write a custom Python script so that I can serve the same index.html file at http://127.0.0.1:8000/context/index.html

Comment: in your http handler parse the path in parts and fetch the appropriate file

Answer (score 1):

sth like this, only you need to parse the request path into parts if you need more refined approach (adapted from test python server, use as needed):

```
# a simple custom http server
class TestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        # if the main path is requested
        # load the template and output it
        if  self.path == "/" or self.path == "":
            out = Contemplate.tpl('main', main_template_data)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(out)))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes(out, 'UTF-8'))
            return
        # else do the default behavior for other requests
        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


# start the server
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer((IP, PORT), TestHandler)
print("Application Started on http://%s:%d" % (IP, PORT))
httpd.serve_forever()
```